# VS Code SSH into remote linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, visual-studio-code

Can someone give me a tip on how to troubleshoot remoting into a remote Linux platform via SSH through VS Code?

SSH works just fine through Windows Terminal with the same user account but now I cannot connect with VS Code on the same user account.

Any ideas to try?

the SSH Settings file, looks fine:

```
Host 192.168.0.100
  HostName 192.168.0.100
  User pi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of dealing is to have the `key.pem` and then mention that in the `IdentityFile` section of the `config` file

```
Host 192.168.0.100
  HostName 192.168.0.100
  User PI
  IdentityFile C:\<YOUR PATH TO PEM KEY>\temp.pem
```

Comment: any tips on how to create the pem file?

Comment: Login to your remote machine with same user you want to connect through VS Code. Run `ssh-keygen` on your remote linux and it will generate the new pair of keys (Public and private) and you can use the private key `.pem` in you `IdentityFile` configuration

Make sure you dont have the ssh key pair already present in the .ssh directory of the remote linux before running `ssh-keygen`.

It will break any other connection with you remote.